# IE 10: cannot get elements with name composed with only digit

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have this problem with IE 10. I have this code inside a form in an HTML page:

```
<input type='hidden' name='X123' />
<input type='hidden' name='123' />
<input type='hidden' name='00123' />
```

If I run this JS command:

```
document.forms['MyForm'].elements[name];
```

where `name` are the names of the inputs, I can get only the first (`'X123'`). In the other two cases the function returns `undefined`. I tested it on IE 10 and Firefox. On Firefox works. However, it has to run under IE. This is a MWE:

```
<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>
function println(text) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<p>' + text + '</p>';
}
function test() {
    println('X123 = '  + document.forms['MyForm'].elements['X123']);
    println('123 = '   + document.forms['MyForm'].elements['123']);
    println('00123 = ' + document.forms['MyForm'].elements['00123']);
}
</script></head><body onload='test();'><form name='MyForm'>
<input type='hidden' name='X123' />
<input type='hidden' name='123' />
<input type='hidden' name='00123' />
</form><div id='output'></div></body></html>
```

I need to know if this is a known behavior of IE.

**A better explanation**: I bump into this problem at work. I made the HTML you see *just to replicate the problem* (it is not a tutorial). I know I can use jQuery or other methods to get the elements by name, but I need to know if this is a known behavior of IE because I can't find anything about on the net.

Comment: do you check `document.forms['MyForm'].elements` collection?

Comment: Note: `<body onload='javascript:test();'>` should be `<body onload='test();'>` (if you're going to use an `onload` at all, which you probably shouldn't) -- e.g., no `javascript:`. The content of `onXyz` attributes is script code. You only use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol where a URL is expected, such as `<a href="...">`.

Comment: Where are you getting this code from? If it's new from a tutorial, try a different one.

Comment: `document.forms['MyForm'].elements` return _HTMLCollection_ and from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection): _Currently HTMLCollections does not recognize purely numeric IDs, which would cause conflict with the array-style access, though HTML5 does permit these._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to know if this is a known behavior of IE.

Not just IE; [that code](http://jsbin.com/vimupi) doesn't work on Chrome or Firefox either, for the `123` element. [Grundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2881286/grundy) seems to have found [the relevant info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) about why, which is that all-digits names cause confusion with index-based access, and so aren't available by name.

> ...and if exists a workaround.

Yes, you can use `querySelector` instead (available on all modern browsers, and also IE8). I don't have IE10 handy, but it works for me on IE8, IE9, IE11, Chrome, and Firefox (the original code doesn't work in any of them) so I'd say it almost certainly works on IE10 as well:

```
println('X123 = '  + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="X123"]'));
println('123 = '   + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="123"]'));
println('00123 = ' + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="00123"]'));
```

Note that the quotes around the values in `[name="value"]` are important, because otherwise the ones starting with digits are a CSS syntax error.

**Live Example:**

```js
function println(text) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<p>' + text + '</p>';
}
function test() {
    println('X123 = '  + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="X123"]'));
    println('123 = '   + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="123"]'));
    println('00123 = ' + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="00123"]'));
}
test();
```

```html
<form name='MyForm'>
<input type='hidden' name='X123' value="X123 value"/>
<input type='hidden' name='123' value="123 value"/>
<input type='hidden' name='00123' value="00123 value" />
</form><div id='output'></div>
```

And if you want their values:

```
println('X123 = '  + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="X123"]']).value);
println('123 = '   + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="123"]']).value);
println('00123 = ' + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="00123"]']).value);
```

```js
function println(text) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<p>' + text + '</p>';
}
function test() {
    println('X123 = '  + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="X123"]').value);
    println('123 = '   + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="123"]').value);
    println('00123 = ' + document.forms['MyForm'].querySelector('[name="00123"]').value);
}
test();
```

```html
<form name='MyForm'>
<input type='hidden' name='X123' value="X123 value"/>
<input type='hidden' name='123' value="123 value"/>
<input type='hidden' name='00123' value="00123 value" />
</form><div id='output'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to avoid using names or IDs that start with numbers, as the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) says.

You may solve this problem by pre-pending something to the name, e.g:

```
name="123"  -->  name="whatever-123"
```

Comment: Agreed. Add a prefix to them. Using plain numeric IDs and names is bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for referencing HTML 4 specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
document.forms['MyForm'].elements[name];
```

The reason this is a problem with numeric names is because `.elements` can be referenced as a collection -- ie with numeric references to get the fields in sequence -- as well as with names.

Therefore, giving it a numeric name means that it gets confused as to whether you mean the element named '123' or the 123rd element in the form. You mean the former, but it tries to give you the latter.

The solution is simple: just add an alphabetic prefix to them.